# Layout: Have component content push the next components content down with overlapping backgrounds

Tags: html, css, layout, components

This trend has been here for a while, yet I haven't come up with a decent solution.

I have two separate components that have a different coloured background and I need the content of the first component to push over into the second component, and thus push its content down.

I'm not even sure if its possible. This is basically how they would be structured:

```
<div class=”component-1 blue”>
  <!-- This block of content should push down any content in a preceding component -->
  <div class=”content-1”></div>
</div>

<div class=”component-2 pink”>
  <!-- This block of content should get pushed down because of the block above it. Without the one above, it wouldn't be pushed down. -->
  <div class=”content-2”></div>
</div>
```

This is what it should look like when component 1 pushes component 2s content down.

[image]

And this is what it would look like when component 1 isn't there to push component 2 down.

[image]

Ideally the solution wouldn't have a style set something like this:

```
.component-1 + .component-2 {...} // Now push component-2 down a set amount.
```

Since that would mean every component built, would need to have that style added just in case it appears after component-1. And if the content of component-1 changes, we'd need to change things up again.

[And here is a JSFiddle setup of it not working](https://jsfiddle.net/r9afbp0j/), if you'd like to give it a try.

I've tried using floats, collapsing margins, setting a specific height. I feel like it might be possible, but also might not be possible.

How would you approach this problem so that it scales well, and components can easily be moved around without breaking the site.

Comment: Since the height of the elements is unknown, I think you're gonna neeed JS.  Certainly some positioning would seem to be in order if an element is to exceed the bounds of it's parent.